# Query data after scaffolding the existing database. Error: The navigation '' cannot be added because it targets the keyless entity type

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, ef-core-3.0

My problem is as describe in the title. I am using EF core to scaffold an existing database. It auto generates all the table class files and `DbContext` class. Then I try to query the `Offer` table with `Id = 4341`. However I always get this error.

> The navigation '' cannot be added because it targets the keyless entity type

I have seen someone asked this question before but no clear solution has been provided.

This is how I query the database:

```
using (var context = new Vmob_xbg178_CoreContext())
{
    var offer4341 = context.Offer.Where(s => s.Id == 4341);
}
```

[[image: Error in DbContext class[1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that MessageKeyTag table in your database dose ***not*** have a primary key. EF assumes every entity has key. Otherwise the table will be treated as a view.

Please add a primary key to your keyless table then regenerate the code...

Comment: Thank Yazan, yes you are correct. it work. But I wonder why it relate to that table MessageKeyTag. I query the Offer table and it has no attribute relate to MessageKeyTag table